# The Arqade review buttons color contrast is awful

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The Arqade review buttons color contrast is really bad.  The white color on a very light grey background is really hard to read.  On a technical level, it fails **WCAG AA** and **AAA** for both large and normal font sizes being a color contrast of **1.46:1** (it should be around **3:1**).  While reviewing a little while ago I had to adjust my screen to be able to double check which buttons were which.

[image: Arqade review buttons]

Can we please adjust the review buttons colors to fix this?  I think there may have been recent changes to these buttons, as I don't remember having this issue with them before.

Comment: Not just the review, but also Submit buttons on posts (questions/answers and edits) as well

Comment: I have perfectly good vision and it is somewhat hard for me to read. I can only imagine how difficult it must be for anyone with any type of vision impairment to try and read them.

Comment: Also, for normal text, the ratio should be 4.5:1, and for large text (14 pt. and bold or larger, or 18 pt or larger) it should be 3:1 for AA standards. For AAA standards it should be 7:1 and 4.5:1 respectively.

Comment: I can't be the only one that was confused as to why all the options in the review queue were "greyed out".

Comment: @MrLemon No, that was what I thought at first as well.  As though I wasn't able to actually review anything.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for posting this. There was a problem with button styles not being applied fully to `input` button elements. This has been corrected.

---

**UPDATE:**

Sorry about that. I missed Arqade's base CSS file (for some reason), only updating the meta CSS file. This has been corrected and is building out on production now. Give it a few minutes. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Is it active now?  I just flushed cache and checked and the buttons look to be the same.

Comment: Still not fixed.

Comment: Not fixed for me either.

Comment: @zero298 See my amended message above.

Comment: @Hynes looks good now!